# Select three different points of the set of points specified on the plane that make up the triangle of the largest perimeter

Tags: java

I don't understand how to fix it. I tried in different ways, but I come to one that considers the perimeter as equal to 0. Please help me fix it

```
    ArrayList<Point2D.Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    Random r = new Random(); 
    Point2D.Double p = new Point2D.Double();
    
    System.out.print("Enter the number of points that will make up the set: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        p.x = r.nextDouble()*10;
        p.y = r.nextDouble()*10;
        list.add(p);
        System.out.print("\n " + p.x + "," + p.y);
    }
    System.out.println();
    double max = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<size; k++)
            {
                double xi = list.get(i).x, xj = list.get(j).x, xk = list.get(k).x;
                double yi = list.get(i).y, yj = list.get(j).y, yk = list.get(k).y;
                double t1=Math.pow(xi-xj, 2) + Math.pow(yi-yj, 2);
                t1 = Math.sqrt(t1);
                double t2=Math.pow(xi-xk, 2) + Math.pow(yi-yk, 2);
                t2 = Math.sqrt(t2);
                double t3=Math.pow(xk-xj, 2) + Math.pow(yk-yj, 2);
                t3 = Math.sqrt(t3);
                if(t1+t2<t3 && t1+t3<t2 && j+k<i && t2+t3+t1>max) max = t1+t2+t3;
                System.out.print("\nP = "+ max);
            }
    System.out.print("\nP = "+ max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `Point2D.Double` is mutable, so by creating one and setting its x and y values and adding it to the list over and over again you end up with a list with many copies of the same point, all of which have the same x, y coordinates: the last ones entered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow the comparison conditions (perhaps you are trying to optimise these loops before getting the function correct). Isn't it simply the maximum perimeter:

```java
// if(t1+t2<t3 && t1+t3<t2 && j+k<i && t2+t3+t1>max) max = t1+t2+t3;
double perimeter = t2 + t3 + t1;
if (perimeter > max) {
  max = perimeter;
  // TODO record winning i,j,k
}
```

PS it's `O(N^3)` complexity in default form but comes down to `O(NlogN)` with this:

```java
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
      for(int j=i+1; j<size; j++)
        for(int k=j+1; k<size; k++)
```